# wp_enqueue_style -- get_template_uri - loading css in main dir but not from assets/css

Tags: css

I'm working on building a WP theme and am having an issue loading the style sheet.

When the style.css is in the themes main dir it loads fine on my local host.

However, when I put the style.css into my assets/css folder ( in the same theme directory) the theme no longer loads.

Also, would there be a similar command for loading all the images that are in the image folder in that same asset directory?

My current function:

```
function Delta_register_styles (){

    $version = wp_get_theme() -> get ('Version');
    wp_enqueue_style('gfont1', "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;0,900;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap", "/style.css", array(), '$version', 'all');
  
    wp_enqueue_style('gfont2', "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman:wght@400;700&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&family=Sacramento&display=swap", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('delta-bootstrap', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('delta-css', get_template_directory_uri(). "/style.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
   
    wp_enqueue_style('delta-fontawesome', "https://kit.fontawesome.com/ef786af6a6.js", "/style.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Delta_register_styles');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is quite firm about where certain files must be stored.

In your case:

> In order for WordPress to recognize the set of theme template files as a valid theme, the style.css file needs to be located in the root directory of your theme, not a subdirectory.

See [WP developer documentation on the positioning of style.css](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20for%20WordPress%20to%20recognize%20the%20set,the%20%E2%80%9CStylesheets%E2%80%9D%20section%20of%20Enqueuing%20Scripts%20and%20Styles.)

In other words, for some files you cannot choose to put them into subfolders - even if that seems logical!

Comment: That's a great reference thank you! I realized because I saw a css folder in the assets file, I figured that's where the style.css would go, but now I see otherwise!